# Problema com request que so cai no catch

Tags: android, mobile, kotlin, request

Estou trabalhando ne um projeto novo então nao tenho muito dominio do codigo e cheguei a um problema onde a request nao funciona ou retorna algo onde eu nao consigo resolver , ela so cai no catch.

Esta e a função onde eu chamo a função login()

```
override suspend fun authenticate(userCredentials: UserCredentials, callback: AuthView) =
    try {
        when (val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { login(userCredentials) }) {
            is ResultRemote.Success -> callback.onSuccess(result.response)
            is ResultRemote.ErrorResponse -> callback.onError(result.codError.mapErrorType())
        }
    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        Log.e("mistake#6" , "Message:" + throwable.message.toString()  + " LocalizedMessage:" + throwable.localizedMessage.toString()
                + " Cause:" + throwable.cause.toString())
        callback.onError(throwable.mapRemoteErrors().codError.mapErrorType())

    }
```

função login

```
  override suspend fun login(userCredentials: UserCredentials): ResultRemote<UserAccessToken> {
    return try {

        val accessToken = service.login(userCredentials)
        ResultRemote.Success(
            response = accessToken
        )

    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        Log.e("mistake#4" , "Message:" + throwable.message.toString()  + " LocalizedMessage:" + throwable.localizedMessage.toString()
                + " Cause:" + throwable.cause.toString())
        throwable.mapRemoteErrors()
    }
}
```

dentro do service.login

```
 @POST(Route.AUTH)
suspend fun login(@Body login: UserCredentials): UserAccessToken
```

Retorno do log:

```
Message: Job was cancelled Localized/ Message:Job was cancelled/ Cause: null
```

Comment: userCredentials por acaso esta null? Segundo a mensagem, a causa do erro eh "null" - entao alguem pode estar nulo.

Comment: Acabei de verificar e os campos estão com dados , tentei retirar a request de dentro das funções acima e fazer a parte e funcionou porem ainda precisava dela dentro da fun authenticate

Comment: Mas qual é o throwable que tá dando? você só colocou a mensagem dele.